# TextView Array not working?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

here is my code:

```
public class fm_weapons extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView display;
TextView dis;
TextView[] textViewArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.weapons);

    display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.empty);
    dis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyText);
    textViewArray= new TextView[] {(TextView)findViewById(R.id.k_k),(TextView)findViewById(R.id.s_s), 
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.h_d) };

     ......
    kk_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ss_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    hd_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
 }
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.kk_btn:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.king_k);
        dis.setText(textViewArray[0].getText());
        break;
    case R.id.ss_btn:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.start_s);
        dis.setText(textViewArray[1].getText());
        break;
    case R.id.hd_btn:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.hidden_d);
        dis.setText(textViewArray[2].getText());
        break;

}
```

what I am trying to do is, as you can see I have 3 buttons and I want when someone clicks one of them to represent the textview assigned to them (check the image for a better understanding). My TextViews are written in an other xml to in the main xml that I am working on because I don't any of them to appear in the main xml except if they are called.

[image]

Using the code above gives me this error in the logcat:

```
08-15 19:27:57.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2067): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 19:27:57.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2067): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 19:27:57.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at     com.example.guide.fm_weapons.onClick(fm_weapons.java:153)
08-15 19:27:57.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at     android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
08-15 19:27:57.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
08-15 19:27:57.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-15 19:27:57.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-15 19:27:57.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-15 19:27:57.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
08-15 19:27:57.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 19:27:57.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-15 19:27:57.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-15 19:27:57.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-15 19:27:57.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2067):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-15 19:27:59.365: E/Trace(2106): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

this is line #153:

```
dis.setText(textViewArray[0].getText());
```

the xml of the textview:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/k_k"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:text="Increases defense"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/s_s"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:text="Increases strenght." />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/h_d"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:text="Restores MP." />
```

Any Idea how to fix this, that would be great if you are able to help me, Thanks

Comment: which part of the xml @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: the three textView above in the array

Comment: you can put your textviews in the same layout as your buttons and make them visible on buttonclick

Comment: @user3487063  can you tell me how to do that. the part of make them visible on buttonclick

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin i added the textviews

Comment: textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Comment: @user3896367 post the entire weapons xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text views are on different layout file, then you need to get them using:

```
LayoutInflater inflater 
                 = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                  .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.<yourtextviewlayout>, null); 
TextView t = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.k_k);
```

.... get other textviews too and add them to an array

or keep them in same layout as your buttons and make them visible on button click:

```
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

by default have them invisible by setting it in layout xml using:

```
android:visibility="false"
```

Comment: sorry but what should i replace context with

Comment: you should replace "yourtextviewlayout" with name of the xml file where textviews are, no need to change anything in the first line, see my edit

Comment: easiest thing would be to have your textviews in same layout as buttons and make them visibile and invisible as you want